# Cryptography question

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

I think this is a pohlig hellman symmetric key system working in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Assuming Alice and Bob both have p (a prime) and k (a key)

If Alice sends $m^k$ to Bob, can Bob raise $m^k$ to $k^{-1}$ to retrieve $m$?

I tried it with $p=7, k=2, k^{-1}= 4$ and $m=3$ but it didnt work:

$(3^2)^4 \equiv 9^4 \equiv 2^4 \equiv 2 \not \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$.

Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: We have [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, it doesn't quite work the way you did it.  This is because you'd want to calculate the inverse of $k$, but *not* mod $p$.  You'd actually want to look at $\phi(p) = p-1$, and calculate the inverse of $k$, mod $(p-1)$.  (Here $\phi$ is the Euler phi-function.)

Note that in your example, this is actually impossible, since $2$ is not invertible mod $6$ (because $gcd(2, 6) \neq 1$).  This indicates that you shouldn't have chosen the key $k=2$.

So let's try a slightly different example.  Take $p = 17$, so $\phi(p) = 16$, and use the key $k = 11$.  Now if we wish to send the message $m = 2$, we'd encrypt by calculating
$$
2^{11} (\textrm{mod }17),
$$
which is $8$.  So we'd send the cipher-text $8$.

Now, to decrypt the received message, we'll use the inverse of of our key $k=11$, mod 16 (not 17).  We see that $11^{-1} = 3 (\textrm{mod }16)$, since $11 * 3 = 33 = 1 (\textrm{mod }16)$.  So we'll raise $8^3\textrm{mod }17$.  The result is the original message, $m=2$.

Why do we need $k^{-1}$ mod $\phi(p)$ instead of mod $p$?  This is due to Euler's Theorem (or Fermat's Theorem):
$$
a^{\phi(n)} = 1 (\textrm{mod }n)
$$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Therefore if we let $u = k^{-1} (\textrm{mod }\phi(p))$, so that $u*k = 1 (\textrm{mod }\phi(p))$, then:
$$
(m^k)^u = m^{k  u} = (m^{1 + t*\phi(p)}) = (m^{\phi(p)})^t*m^1 = 1^t * m = m (\textrm{mod }p)
$$

This is related to how RSA works.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Can you explain why i need to work in ϕ(p). Is it because discrete logs are only defined in ϕ(p)?

Comment: Well, it's due to Euler's Theorem (or Fermat's Theorem, which is weaker but perfectly fine for this application).  If you accept Euler's Theorem, then the last chain of equations in my answer is supposed to be the reason for using $\phi(p)$.  (Basically, in the *exponent*, you'll reduce mod $\phi(p)$.  Reducing mod $p$ in the *exponent* simply doesn't work, as you yourself noted!)